# need to refresh web page after clicking close on pop-up window

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a pop-up window a user logs into, once they are logged in successful, I have a message that has a link to close the window. But I want it to not only close that pop up window, but I want it to refresh the webpage the pop-up window was clicked on.

So the page can refresh to see that there is a valid login session for that user.

Is this possible w/ jQuery?

Comment: If you're going to refresh the page in this manner, why bother using a pop-up/javascript to log in in the first place? Why not have login controls in a lightbox like div, and have that cause the page to post?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In your popup window:

```
$('#closeButton').click(function(e) {
    window.opener.location.reload(true);
    window.close();
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Reloads the parent page and closes the popup.

Comment: Returning `false` from a handler is equivalent to calling both `.preventDefault()` and `.stopPropagation()` on the event object.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
window.location.reload()
```

It just tells javascript to reload the page, this is not dependent on jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

```
onclick="javascript:window.opener.location.reload(true);self.close();"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code that refresh parent window and closes the popup in one operation.

```
<script language="JavaScript">
<!--
function refreshParent() {
  window.opener.location.href = window.opener.location.href;

  if (window.opener.progressWindow) {
     window.opener.progressWindow.close()
  }
  window.close();
}
//-->
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code in `ajaxlogin.js` file for mvc 4 user

```
$('#closeButton').click(function(e) {
    window.opener.location.reload(true);
    window.close();
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Its working fine

Answer (score 0):

Works efficiently for me:

```
$(window).unload(function() {
   if (!window.opener.closed) {
      window.opener.__doPostBack('', '');
      e.preventDefault();
   }
});
```

Comment: In firefox the code won't popup a Confirm box asking **"To display this page, Firefox must send information that will repeat any action (such as a search or order confirmation) that was performed earlier."**

Answer (score 0):

Use this code in window close event like

```
$('#close').click(function(e) {
    window.opener.location.reload();
    window.close();
   self.close();
});
```

http://www.delhincrjob.com/blog/how-to-close-popup-window-and-refresh-parent-window-in-jquery/